# Find shift direction for min overlap area of 2 polygons

Tags: computational-geometry, polygons

I have 2 arbitrary polygons (concave or convex) with certain overlap.
Now there is some relative shift between these 2 polygons (vector s with a constant length).
I want to find the direction of s which will minimize the overlapped area.
Runtime speed is a big concern.

Thanks,

Yenwen

Comment: How exactly are the polygons encoded?

Comment: Polygons can be represented as vertices in linked lists.